# Character number of match in Perl

Tags: perl, search

How can I make Perl to tell me the character number of a match, for example in a text file I have:

```
CHI (3) - NSH (1)        
DAL (4) - CHI (3)        
VAN (3) - CHI (2)
```

Want I want to get is for CHI the character number in which appears, for example:

```
Line 1: 0
Line 2: 9
Line 3: 9
```

Any ideas or hints?.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see [perldoc -f index](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html)

Answer (score 3):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use English qw<$INPUT_LINE_NUMBER>;

open my $fh, '<', '/path/to/file/I/want' or die "Could not open file!";
while ( <$fh> ) {
    printf "Line %d: %d\n",  $INPUT_LINE_NUMBER, index( $_, 'CHI' );
}
close $fh;
```

Answer (score 1):

Index solutions as posted here are fine,
but for learning purpose, you could also
use a regular expression, eg.:

```
...

while( <$fh> ){
    /CHI/g && print "Line $.: $-[0]\n" 
}

...
```

would print your desired output. This would even make a fancy one-liner:

```
$> perl -lne '/CHI/g && print "Line $.: $-[0]"' data.txt
```

Regards

rbo